# Adding data to the table for radio button but columns are not showing except 1st column

Tags: angular, dynamic, html-table, radio-button, radio-group

Not getting the other columns and rows. Below is my ts file where I have split the data coming from API. I am getting the data from api to the dataSource that are column values of first column. BUt not getting other values in other table cells.

```
formArray = new FormArray([
    new FormControl(),
    new FormControl(),
    new FormControl(),
  ]);
  displayColumns: any[] = [];
  dataSource : any[] = [];
  allColumns = ['question', ...this.displayColumns];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.questionSettin = JSON.parse(this.question_setting) 
    console.log(this.questionSettin[0].value);
    
    var ab = this.QuestionOptions[0].option_description;
    ab = ab.replace("{",'');
    ab = ab.replace("}",'');
    ab=ab.replace('"row":','');
    ab=ab.replace('"columns":','');
    ab=ab.replace(/'/g, '');
    ab=ab.replace(/"/g,'');
    var aa = ab.split(',');
    var row = aa[0].split("\\n");
    var cols = aa[1].split("\\n");

    console.log(row);
    console.log(cols);
    console.log(aa);

    this.dataSource = row;
    console.log('dataSource',this.dataSource,cols);
    this.displayColumns = cols;
  }
```

Comment: your code example is incomplete. But it looks like you have a `mat-radio-group`for every radio button. You should probably use only one `mat-radio-group` per row

Comment: Nope this is the only code for the radio button. And this code only generates all the radio buttons shown in image

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I had to assign the 'question' to `this.allColumns` by concating it with 'cols' in ngOnInit. The error was it was not taking the row question because I only assigned question to the allColumns variable.

```
this.displayColumns=cols;
    this.allColumns=['question',...cols];
    console.log("display col")
    console.log(this.displayColumns)
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you want to control the values using a FormArray of FormControls, so imagine some like

```
formArray=new FormArray([
    new FormControl(2),
    new FormControl(2),
    new FormControl(3),
  ])
  dataValue=["1","2","3"]
  displayColumns: string[] = [
     'col1',
    'col2',
    'col3',
  ];
```

You can use a simple table in the way

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let control of formArray.controls;let row=index">
    <td>{{'row '+row}}</td>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let innerColumn of displayColumns;let i=index">
    <td >
       <mat-radio-button [value]="dataValue[i]" [name]="'rd'+row"
        [checked]="formArray.at(row).value==dataValue[i]" 
        (change)="formArray.at(row).setValue(dataValue[i])"></mat-radio-button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See that you iterate over `formArray.controls;let row=index` and use the "row" to give name to the mat-radio-button and to control the formArray.at(row). We use the index "i" for columns to give value to the radio buttons: dataValue[i] and when change give value to the formArray

We **not** use mat-radio-group and use the [checked] and (checked) property /event of the mat-radio-button

if you want to use a mat-table is similar

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="formArray.controls">
  <ng-container
    *ngFor="let innerColumn of displayColumns;let i=index"
    [matColumnDef]="innerColumn"
  >
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{'col '+row}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let row=index">
      <mat-radio-button
        [value]="dataValue[i]"
        [name]="'rd'+row"
        [checked]="formArray.at(row).value==dataValue[i]"
        (change)="formArray.at(row).setValue(dataValue[i])"
      ></mat-radio-button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Again we have two index "row" and "i"

You can see in [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4tnhk9-up5am7?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html,src%2Fmain.ts)

**Update** to be more concrete. If imagine we has two arrays

```
  rows=[{value:1,name:'option 1'},
        {value:2,name:'option 2'}, 
        {value:1,name:'option 3'}]

  cols=[{value:10,description:'excelent'},
        {value:8,description:'good'},
        {value:3,description:'pour'},
        {value:1,description:'bad'}]
```

We relationate the other variables like

```
  formArray=new FormArray(this.rows.map(x=>new FormControl(x.value)))

  displayColumns=this.cols.map(x=>x.description);
  allColumns=['name',...this.displayColumns]
  dataValue=this.cols.map(x=>x.value)
```

I update the stackblitz too

**Update two** it's not related

When we want to generate "something" that depend of one or more Inputs we can not use ngOnInit else we create our @Inputs as setters, e.g. if depend of two inputs

```
  //define outside
  QuestionOptions: IOption[] = [];
  @Input('QuestionOptions') _QuestionOptions(value: IOption[]){
     this.QuestionOptions=value;
     this.createGrid();
  }

  //idem with other Input

  //define outside
  question_setting: string = ''
  @Input('question_setting') _question_setting(value:string){
      this.question_setting=value;
      this.createGrid();
  }

  //finally our function createGrid
  createGrid()
  {
       if (this.QuestionOptions.length && this.question_setting){
             ...here we makes all the calculates...
       }
  }
```

Comment: Hii @Eliseo I have done as you have shown. I am getting the data from API and I have splitted the string to divide string into value. And I am getting those values to the first column but not able to get it to the other columns like I am not able to get the displayColumn and radioButtons. I have updated the question ith the TS file. It ill be very helpful to me if you make me undrstand why I am getting this problem. Thank you

Comment: @MeetShah, can you edit your question adding an e.g. of the result of the API? (almost the first element)

Comment: I have changed the question thank you. I am new to Stack Overflow. Can you guide me the error and the solution I can do here?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4tnhk9-895np2?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.css


this is the link where I have added my code to html and ts file

Comment: @MeetShah, sorry I can not see the way of your `questionSettin` I update the answer (and the stackblitz) using two arrays

Comment: questionsettin is not related to this. Its for the mandatory field. I am able to do it statically but when I fetch data from the api then this error occurs, only first column is visible.

Comment: If depend of one `@Input` don't put the code in ngOnInit else create a setter and put the code to generate in the setter: `@Input('yourInput') set _yourInput(value){..this.yourInput=value; ...here...})`. Really is more tidy create an auxiliar function and this can help us if the calculations depend of more than one input